# mysql2 gem insisting on using openssl 1.0 instead of 1.1

Tags: ruby, openssl

I have recently updated openssl to 1.1 and reinstalled ruby 2.5.3 for one of our rails apps.

However I'm getting the error:

```
/Users/cameron/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require': dlopen(/Users/cameron/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.10/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.20.dylib
  Reason: image not found - /Users/cameron/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.10/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
```

In my `.zshrc` I have the following in my path:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/bin:$PATH"
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include"
```

And I have tried uninstalling mysql2 and reinstalling like so:

```
gem install mysql2 -v 0.4.10 -- --with-cflags=\"-I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include\" --with-ldflags=\"-L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib\"
```

But the error keeps coming back up...

Why is the mysql2 gem still trying to use `1.0.0` instead `1.1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that encounters this issue... the fix is rather annoying but simple.

Quite literally do:

`source ~/.zshrc` or `source ~/.bash_profile`

You don't even need to use the `--with-cflags --with-ldflags`... and reinstall your mysql2 gem. Once you have re-linked your profile with the openssl in the path, a simple `bundle install` is sufficient and everything will work again!